# Como fazer data mining em um arquivo txt com re.finditer

Tags: python

Este código consegue indicar-me a localização das palavras `batman` e `sei` em todo o arquivo `txt`:

```
import re
f = open('C:/pah.txt','r+')
text = f.read()    
words = ['batman','sei']
for x in words:
 for m in re.finditer(x,text):
  print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0))
```

Como consigo que o resultado devolvido inclua a frase em que está a palavra encontrada?

O arquivo `pah.txt` é este:

> olha o batman. eu sou batman.nao sei.eu sei.Mas e qual será a razão
>   para eu saber? nÃO sei

E o resultado pretendido deveria ser:

```
10-16 olha o batman.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse caso, você precisa de uma expressão regular que case a frase inteira, e não somente a palavra desejada. O que é uma frase?

- Algo que não possui `.`, `?` nem `!` e:
- Algo que acaba com `.`, `?` ou `!`.

Então a expressão regular que procura uma frase [qualquer] é:

```
[^.!?]*[.!?]
```

E para achar uma frase contendo a palavra "batman" você usaria:

```
[^.!?]*?(batman)[^.!?]*[.!?]
```

Os parênteses em torno de "batman" formam um [grupo de captura](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - para você saber depois em que parte da frase a palavra encontrada apareceu. Para isso, basta passar como parâmetros para `start` e `end` o número do grupo que te interessa (`1`)

```
for x in words:
    for m in re.finditer('[^.!?]*?(' + x + ')[^.!?]*[.!?]', text):
        print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(1), m.end(1), m.group(0))
```

Saída:

```
07-13: olha o batman.
22-28:  eu sou batman.
33-36: nao sei.
40-43: eu sei.
```

Nota: se o que você quer é a posição inicial e final da palavra **em relação à frase** (e não em relação à string toda) então basta subtrair da posição do grupo de captura a posição do match inteiro:

```
        print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(1)-m.start(), m.end(1)-m.start(), m.group(0))
```

Saída:

```
07-13: olha o batman.
08-14:  eu sou batman.
04-07: nao sei.
03-06: eu sei.
```

Comment: Perfeito, compreendi finalmente o porquê de se usar [^.!?]*[.!?]

Answer (score 5):

Para obter as frases completas, você pode fazer assim:

```
import re

f = open('C:/pah.txt','r+')
text = f.read() 

words = ['batman','sei']

for x in words:
    sentences = [sentence for sentence in re.split('\.|\?|!', text) if x in sentence]

    for sentence in sentences:
        print sentence
```

O output fica assim:

```
olha o batman
 eu sou batman
nao sei
eu sei
Mas e qual será a razão para eu saber
nÃO sei
```

(não entendi o que significam as posições "10-16" do exemplo que você passou.)

Comment: Assumindo que existam 3 espaços em branco no começo do arquivo, `10-16` se refere à posição da palavra "batman" em relação à frase (ou à string inteira, não está claro). i.e. `b` está na posição `10` e `n` na posição `15` (`16-1`).

Comment: Faz sentido.. Talvez tenha uns espaços ou linebreaks no começo do arquivo dele. Vou adaptar o meu código considerando isso.

Comment: Apesar que o seu ficou bem melhor, hahah...

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas. Sim, o 10-16 refere-se à posição do início e fim da palavra em relação à string toda. Mais uma vez, obrigado pela resposta, Michael.